# C++ Segfault when returning an empty vector containing vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, segmentation-fault

I'm having some trouble returning an empty vector which I wasn't expecting. Can anybody help explain please!

This is the offending section: - I am aware the returns are the same, its a placeholder for now.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > PerceptronLayer::calculateLayer() {
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > result;

    if (vPerceptrons.size() == 0) {
        return result;
    }

    return result;
}
```

If however I make sure that the vector has some values, by setting some dummy data, the function returns as I would expect.

```
    std::vector<double> val;
    val.push_back(1.0);
    result.push_back(val);
```

GDB output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040ba60 in std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >::operator[]     (this=0x0, __n=0)
at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:751
751       { return *(this->_M_impl._M_start + __n); }
```

I could protect the function by not allowing it to run on empty data, but I can't help but feel im missing something fundamental here.

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Can you show us the complete code ? Its difficult to say what is wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: Use GDB command `up` to go through the call stack. It looks like somewhere in your code the return value is assumed to be non-empty.

Comment: Ah, ok. Yeah I think ive found it. I had the return going to: std::vector<std::vector<double> > results = pl.calculateLayer();  If I split this out onto two lines it works:    std::vector<std::vector<double> > results;
  results = pl.calculateLayer();

Comment: @joeButler This result looks very interesting. Single line is using copy constructor while double lines is using assignment operator overloading. Why could this happen? I tried this on Visual Studio but everything was fine. Did gcc/g++ have different implementation on this?

Comment: The error is in the code you're not showing us. You're using the unchecked `std::vector<>::operator[]()` array-operator in at least one place on a vector you never checked for content (i.e. you didn't `v.size() > N` before attempting to access `v[N]`).

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense now. Its something I can look out for better in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by  - See question comments for details.

Originally I had the return from the posted function going to setup a new vector. Which it didn't like.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > results = pl.calculateLayer();
```

If I split this same code out onto two lines it works as expected. I guess the constructor / copy for std::vector didn't like being given this.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > results; 
results = pl.calculateLayer();
```

Comment: I tried similar code on both visual studio 2010 and Centos 5.9 x86 with gcc 4.1.2 (I installed one with virtual box on my laptop to verify this), but everything was fine. It doesn't make sense that copy constructor and assignment operator overloading have this significant difference. May I know what platform and compiler you used?

Comment: gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.7-2ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.4 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug

Comment: --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu